# A question related to partial sum of series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

This question was asked in a masters exam for which I am preparing and I was unable to solve it.

> Questtion: Let $S_n =\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}$ . Then which one of the following is true:

(i) $S_{2^n} \geq n/2$ for every $n\geq1$.

(ii)$|S_{2^n} -S_{2^{n-1}}|\to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

For (ii) the difference is $\frac{1}{2^n} \to 0$ so I think (ii) is true but answer is $1$.

For (i) I don't have any clue on how to manipulate the LHS of the inequality.

Kindly tell me what mistake I am making and how to prove (i). Thanks!!

Comment: You are mistaking $|S_{2^{n}}-S_{2^{n-1}}|$ for $|S_{2^{n}}-S_{2^{n}-1}|$

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy It was typo in my book . Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prove part (i) is true:

$$
{\small
\begin{align}
S_{2^n} &= 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \left( \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4} \right)+ \left( \frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{7} + \frac{1}{8} \right) + \left( \frac{1}{9} + \cdots + \frac{1}{16} \right) + \cdots + \left( \frac{1}{2^{n-1}+1} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2^n} \right) \\
\\
&\ge 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \left( \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4} \right)+ \left( \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{8} \right) + \left( \frac{1}{16} + \cdots + \frac{1}{16} \right) + \cdots + \left( \frac{1}{2^n} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2^n} \right) \\
\\
&= 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} + \cdots +  \frac{1}{2} \\
\\
&= 1 + n \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)
\end{align}
}
$$

To show part (ii) is false, note that using the regrouping shown above, we get that

$$
{\small
\begin{align}
S_{2^n} - S_{2^{n-1}} &= \frac{1}{2^{n-1}+1} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2^n} \\
\\
& \ge \frac{1}{2}
\end{align}
}
$$

Answer (score 0):

You are mistaking $|S_{2^{n}}-S_{2^{n-1}}|$ for $|S_{2^{n}}-S_{2^{n}-1}|$. Use comparison with $\int_{2^{n-1}}^{2^{n}} \frac 1 x dx$ to show that ii) is false.

For 1) use induction and the fact that $\frac 1 {2^{n}+1}+\frac 1 {2^{n}+2}+...+\frac 1 {2^{n+1}}\geq \frac {2^{n+1}-2^{n}} {2^{n+1}}=\frac 1  2$ since each term on the left is $\geq \frac 1 {2^{n+1}}$ and there are $2^{n+1}-2^{n}$ terms.